# Change the size of the cursor

Tags: cursor, line-spacing

How can I prevent the height of a vertical cursor to be changed if I increase the line spacing? This is my `.emacs` setup

```
 (setq-default cursor-type 'bar) 
 (setq-default line-spacing 1.15)
```

Comment: Try something like `(setq-default cursor-type '(hbar . 17))` perhaps? But if you are looking to keep it skinny as well as short, I think you are out of luck: I don't think you can control both the width and the height. AFAIK, you gotta choose one.